# Why is $C_n(\coprod X_\alpha)\cong\bigoplus C_n(X_\alpha)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology

I am currently learning homology and I could not understand why is

$$C_n\left(\coprod X_\alpha\right)\cong\bigoplus C_n(X_\alpha).$$

where $C_n$ is the free abelian group generated by $\operatorname{Sing}_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X = \coprod_\alpha X_\alpha$.  There is a natural map
$$
\eta:  \bigoplus_\alpha C_n(X_\alpha) \to C_n(X)
$$
given by adding simplices to get chains:  the set of functions  $f_\alpha: \Delta^n \to X_\alpha$ with the inclusions $i_\alpha: X_\alpha \hookrightarrow X$ defines a chain $\sum_\alpha i_\alpha \circ f_\alpha$ in $X$.  This is easily monic since both groups are free.

Take a basis element of the codomain chain group.  This is a map $f: \Delta^n \to X$.  As $\Delta^n$ is connected and $X$ is a disjoint union, the image of $f$ must land in a single summand $X_\alpha$.  Use this to give an element of $\bigoplus_\alpha C_n(X_\alpha)$ mapping to $f$ under $\eta$.  This shows that $\eta$ is surjective, hence an iso.